# How to sort REST API response in the desired fashion?

Tags: java, rest, api, jsonresponse

```
{
  "data": {
    "uCPE PostStaging Completed": false,
    "Order Submitted": true,
    "uCPE PreStaging Completed": false,
    "Poststaging device deploy success": true,
    "uCPE Activated": false
  },
  "status": "SUCCESS"
}
```

Above mentioned is my Response Body. This keeps changing when a different input is provided. But I want the response only in the following Order. The KEY should be in the below order, however the values for each key will be changing.

```
“Order Submitted”:”true”, 
"Poststaging device deploy success" : “true”,
"uCPE PreStaging Completed": “ true”,
“uCPE PostStaging Completed" : “false”,
“Order Completed”:”false”,
"uCPE Activated":"false"
```

Comment: What code are you using to parse this that cares about the order?

Comment: How are you building ResponseBody json

Comment: @SMaZ Please find the code above

Comment: @prsvr find the code and logic above

Comment: Ok, If you want the original insertion order there are the LinkedXXX classes, which maintain an additional linked list in insertion order. `Linkedlist` and `LinkedHashMap`. This can give performance impact though.

Comment: While Jackson provides the `@JsonPropertyOrder` annotation to return a JSON document with the defined structure, the [JSON spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259) hints that one shouldn't rely on a ordering of JSON. In practice plenty of tools that operate on JSON will shingle the document and therefore fail your needs. I.e. if you want to pretty print json in the console via `json_pp` or the like, it will use hash values instead of the returned order

Comment: @SMaZ LinkedHashMap worked perfect for me. Thank you!

Comment: Great, I will update it in answer section for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jackson, look into `@JsonPropertyOrder`.

In your case it would be something like this:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ 
    "orderSubmitted", 
    "deploySuccess", 
    "preStagingCompleted", 
    "postStaingCompleted", 
    "orderCompleted", 
    "ucpeActivated"
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Alan Sereb and @Roman Vottner suggested, `@JsonPropertyOrder` is best option if you are using your `pojo` class as response.

However, If you are passing `Collection` classes object directly to your parser and want to maintain the order then you need to use `LinkedXXX` or `ArrayList` for list interface. In your case as your are using `Map<List>`, you should use `LinkedHashMap` implementation.

[This](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=65) has very good explanations of `Collection` framework.